# JAXB - unexpected element uri when unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm using **JAXB** to unsmarshal a XML response from a SOAP request, and i'm receiving the following error:

```
unexpected element (uri:"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", local:"NFe"). Expected elements are <{}protNFe>,<{}NFe>
```

This is the relevant part of the received XML:

[...]

```
<XmlNFCe>
    <nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
        <NFe>
            <infNFe versao="3.10" Id="NFe43140215402636000137651040000000161893466508">
                <ide>...
       </NFe>
       <protNFe>...
```

[...]

This class represent the **root** tag. It is the target class that i use to unmarshall:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="XmlNFCe", 
    propOrder={
        "nfeProc"
    })
@XmlRootElement(name="XmlNFCe", namespace="")
public class XmlNfce {

    @XmlElement(name="nfeProc", namespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")
    private NFeProc nfeProc;

    public NFeProc getNfeProc() {
        return nfeProc;
    }

    public void setNfeProc(NFeProc nfeProc) {
        this.nfeProc = nfeProc;
    }
}
```

And this three classes are children tags:

Class One:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="nfeProc", 
    propOrder={
        "NFe",
        "protNFe"
    })
@XmlRootElement(name="nfeProc", namespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe")
public class NFeProc {

    @XmlElement(name="NFe", namespace="", type=NFe.class)
    private NFe NFe;

    @XmlElement(name="protNFe", namespace="", type=ProtNFe.class)
    private ProtNFe protNFe;

    public NFe getNFe() {
        return NFe;
    }

    public void setNFe(NFe nFe) {
        NFe = nFe;
    }

    public ProtNFe getProtNFe() {
        return protNFe;
    }

    public void setProtNFe(ProtNFe protNFe) {
        this.protNFe = protNFe;
    }
}
```

Class Two:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="NFe", 
    propOrder={
        "infNFe",
        "Signature"
    })
@XmlRootElement(name="NFe", namespace="")
public class NFe {

    @XmlElement(name="infNfe")
    private InfNfe infNFe;

    @XmlElement(name="Signature")
    private Signature Signature;

    public InfNfe getInfNFe() {
        return infNFe;
    }

    public void setInfNFe(InfNfe infNFe) {
        this.infNFe = infNFe;
    }

    public Signature getSignature() {
        return Signature;
    }

    public void setSignature(Signature signature) {
        this.Signature = signature;
    }
}
```

Class Three:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="protNFe", 
    propOrder={
        "infProt"
    })
@XmlRootElement(name="protNFe", namespace="")
public class ProtNFe {

    @XmlElement(name="infProt")
    private InfProt infProt;

    public InfProt getInfProt() {
        return infProt;
    }

    public void setInfProt(InfProt infProt) {
        this.infProt = infProt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also show how you do your unmarshalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm remembering incorrectly, XML elements inherit the namespace of their parent if they don't declare one themselves.

So, in

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="3.10">
    <NFe>
        <infNFe versao="3.10" Id="NFe43140215402636000137651040000000161893466508">
            <ide>...
   </NFe>
```

the element `<NFe>` has the same namespace as `<nfeProc>`, ie. `http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe`. However, in your Java classes, they are mapped to a namespace consisting of the empty string `""`.

```
@XmlElement(name="NFe", namespace="", type=NFe.class)
private NFe NFe;

@XmlElement(name="protNFe", namespace="", type=ProtNFe.class)
private ProtNFe protNFe;
```

So the unmarshaller finds an element `<NFe>` with a namespace of `http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe`, but that is not what it expects, as the error says

```
unexpected element (uri:"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe", local:"NFe"). Expected elements are <{}protNFe>,<{}NFe>
```

Just fix your namespace declarations where appropriate.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The returned XML is incorrect and i was neglecting this. I fight with JAXB, but the SOAP response is mal formed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your XML from which you generated you jaxb classes is not right.

In you XML nfeProc is the root element for which you have the namespace defined and the child elements NFE and protNFe do not have a Namespace defined.

to resolve this issue create a seperate Name space for